# how to execute and monitor a long-running process remotely and view output before completion

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, stdout, openssh, parallel-ssh

how can I execute a process on a remote machine and view the standard output before the process exits? ssh is ideal but only reports output once the remote command has completed.

an example python script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time

tStart = time.time()
elapsedTime=0

while elapsedTime<10000:
    time.sleep(2)
    elapsedTime = time.time() - tStart
    print('elapsed time: {0:6.2f}(s)'.format(elapsedTime))
```

generates output indicating it's progress:

```
elapsed time:   2.00(s)
elapsed time:   4.00(s)
elapsed time:   6.00(s)
elapsed time:   8.00(s)
...
```

I'd like to run this on a remote machine with ssh:

```
ssh vector /home/comperem/myProc.py
```

This process will not end for many minutes or hours and I need to monitor the process as it runs.

How can I get ssh or something similar to run the command remotely and report `stdout` to the local console as it is generated, before the remote process completes? Output after each line would be useful.

Comment: Try `tmux` or `screen`. You can also redirect output to system log by `logger`.

Comment: yes, I've changed my use-case to remotely start detached screen processes with parallel-ssh python library. but the basic functionality was solved below by Kenster

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh vector /home/comperem/myProc.py
```

When you invoke a remote program through ssh in this fashion, the remote process runs without a TTY by default. Instead, it is connected to the ssh server through a set of pipes. Your python program is probably buffering its output because it's writing to a pipe rather than a TTY.

The simplest fix is for your program to flush its output. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/230751/13317) discusses how to get a python script to flush standard output. I'm not a python programmer, but it looks like this should work:

```
while elapsedTime<10000:
    time.sleep(2)
    elapsedTime = time.time() - tStart
    print('elapsed time: {0:6.2f}(s)'.format(elapsedTime), flush=True)
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[The other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/230751/13317) discusses other ways to do it.

Comment: outstanding. flushing the buffer was exactly what was needed. it may have worked in block-style output had I been patient enough to wait for enough the buffer to fill. nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve your question with [daggy](https://daggy.dev):

1. Create Data Aggregation Config `config.yaml` like this:

```
aliases:
 - &myProc
   name: myProc
   command: tail -f /home/comperem/myProc.py
   extension: log
 - &auth_ssh
   login: user
   password: password

sources:
   host1:
     type: ssh
     connection:
       *auth_ssh
     host: 192.168.1.10
     commands:
       - *myProc
    hostN:
     type: ssh
     connection:
       *auth_ssh
     host: 192.168.1.N
     commands:
       - *myProc
```

2. Run `daggy -o my_proc_folder config.yaml`
3. Run `tail -f my_proc_folder/*`